# sherlock and the beast in C

Tags: c, puzzle

I'm having a problem while solving this question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast/ and able to solve only 14 test cases out of 15. I am left with Test case #14, if anybody can help me with this.

Here is my Code:

```
int main()
{
int t,i,j,val1=0,val2=0,a0,k,z,five=0,three=0,rem=0,div=0;
int a=5,b=3;

scanf("%d",&t);
for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    rem=n%3;
    div=n/3;
    if(n>2)
    {
    if(n==4)
        {printf("-1\n");}
    if(rem==2){
        three=1;
        five=div-1;
    }
    else if(rem==1){
        three=2;
        five=div-3;
    }
    else if(rem==0)
    {
        three=0;
        five=div;
    }



    for(k=0;k<five;k++){printf("555");}
    for(z=0;z<three;z++){printf("33333");}

}
    else {printf("-1");}
    printf("\n");
}
 return 0;
}
```

Test Case:
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Expected Output:
-1
-1
555
-1
33333
555555
-1
55533333
555555555
3333333333

Comment: Please tell us: your input, your actual output and your expected output.

Comment: Input:
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Expected Output:

-1
-1
555
-1
33333
555555
-1
55533333
555555555
3333333333

Comment: Edit your question and put that in formation there, sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track but a bit more generalization needs to be done. Instead of using "n", a flag needs to be introduced.

```
for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
{   FLAG=1;
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    rem=n%3;
    div=n/3;
    if(rem==2)
        {
            if(div<1)
                FLAG=0;
            five=div-1;
            three=1;
        }
        else if(rem==1)
        {

            if(div<3)
                FLAG=0;
            five=div-3;
            three=2;
        }
        else if(rem==0)
        {
            three=0;
            five=div;
        }

    if(FLAG==1)
    {
            for(k=0;k<five;k++){printf("555");}
            for(z=0;z<three;z++){printf("33333");}
    }
    if(FLAG==0)
        {printf("-1");}
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Hope this would help!